# QuantLibXL no intraday pricing, even with QL_HIGH_RESOLUTION_DATE enabled while compiling

Tags: quantlib

I built QuantLibXL myself following the instruction here: https://www.quantlib.org/quantlibaddin/build_qlxl.html

And in the QuantLib code, I turned on the QL_HIGH_RESOLUTION_DATE flag, before I run the build.

But when I try to price an European option in Excel, I passed in datetime, but I still don't get the intraday price.

[image]

The NPV in the picture should be 0.30003, if I price it in the code, with high resolution timestamp. But I am wondering why this change doesn't go to QuantLibXL?

Is it because I need to use some specific functions? or I need to export some of the QuantLib functions myself?

Thank you!